# Как удалить символы из элемента списка Python?

Tags: python

Прошу помощи т.к. сам не могу нагуглить решение вопроса.
Был список:

```
progression = [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28]
```

Заменил в нём рандомный элемент на `..`

```
rand_progression_index = randint(0, len(progression))
progression[rand_progression_index] = '..'
```

Получил:

```
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, '..', 25, 28]
```

Но по итогу, сейчас, мне нужен список вида:

```
1 4 7 10 13 16 19 .. 25 28
```

Может некорректно делаю, изначально, замену и как-то можно заменить на `..` , а не на `'..'` ?
Возможно, это можно сделать как-то с помощью регулярных варежений `re` в python ?
Прошу помощи, подсказки.
Большое спасибо.

Comment: похоже вам нужна строка, а не список: `" ".join(progression)` ?

Comment: Да, наверное, изначально стоит преобразовать исходный список в строку, потом найти в нём рандомный элемент и заменить его на .. . Пойду пробовать, пока что спасибо большое, вернусь)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш ответ направил меня в правильном направлении: `progression = " ".join(map(str, progression))
 progression = changed_progression.replace(str(mutable_element_value), '..')` Сначала я преобразовал список в строку, после чего с помощью `replace` заменил необходимую мне подстроку и получил необходимый результат! Спасибо!

Comment: @MaxU , как засчитать ваш ответ, как правильный ? Спасибо.

Comment: засчитать правильным можно только ответ, а я написал непроверенный и нерабочий код в __комментарии__ ;) Можете добавить собственный ответ - это нормальная практика на SO

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Jack_oS хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо большое @MaxU! Его ответ направил меня в правильном направлении: `progression = " ".join(map(str, progression))  progression = changed_progression.replace(str(mutable_element_value), '..')` Сначала я преобразовал список в строку, после чего с помощью replace заменил необходимую мне подстроку и получил необходимый результат!

Answer (score 0):

Две точки - это string. Остальные элементы численные. Ответ - никак.
Хотя если я не так понял вопрос и требуется вывести на экран именно такую строку, то советую сперва обработать ее через join.

`print(" ".join(progression))`

Comment: int не join-ится, нужно: `print(" ".join(str(s) for s in progression))`

Comment: Верно, спасибо за помощь, я добился желаемого результата следующим образом: `progression = " ".join(map(str, progression))  progression = changed_progression.replace(str(mutable_element_value), '..')` Сначала я преобразовал список в строку, после чего с помощью replace заменил необходимую мне подстроку и получил необходимый результат! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

распаковывайте список во время вывода

```
print(*progression)
```